# Unable to send large Array of parcelable objects in another actvity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

I have two activity the first activity say Activity1 just gets data from a server filters it and saves it in an arraylist of parcelable objects while displaying a loading screen. After that, Activity1 passes the data it gathered to Acitivty2 which displays it into 2 child fragments.

My problem is that when the list of data in activity1 is few it is successfully passed to activity2 however when it is not, acitivity 2 wont display and starts my other acitivty which is the **MainAcitivty** instead.

Here is the function I used to start my Activity2 from **Activity1**

```
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();       
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_Viewdata_loader.this, Activity_Viewdata.class);
mBundle.putParcelableArrayList("myList", sneardatalist);
intent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

and here is my Activity2 which is the receiver

```
Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
sneardatalist= mBundle.getParcelableArrayList("myList");
```

and my parcelable class looks like this

```
public class sentdata implements Parcelable  {

    private int _id;
    private String _data="";
    private String _lat="";
    private String _long="";
    private String _img="";
    private String _imgP="";
    private int _sntvia;
    private String _snttime="";
    private String _template="";

    public sentdata(){}
    public sentdata( String data, String lat, String longt, String img, String imgp, int sntvia, String sntime, String template  ){
        this._data = data;
        this._lat = lat;
        this._long = longt;
        this._img = img;
        this._imgP = imgp;
        this._sntvia = sntvia;
        this._snttime = sntime;
        this._template = template;
    }

    public sentdata( int id, String data, String lat, String longt, String img, String imgp, int sntvia, String sntime, String template  ){
        this._id = id;
        this._data = data;
        this._lat = lat;
        this._long = longt;
        this._img = img;
        this._imgP = imgp;
        this._sntvia = sntvia;
        this._snttime = sntime;
        this._template = template;
    }

    public int getid(){
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setid(int id){
         this._id = id;
    }
    public void setdata(String data){
        this._data = data;
    }

    public String getdata(){
        return this._data;
    }

    public void setlat(String lat){
        this._lat = lat;
    }

    public String getlat(){
        return this._lat;
    }

    public void setlong(String longt){
        this._long = longt;

    }

    public String getlong(){
        return this._long;
    }

    public void setimg(String img){
        this._img = img;

    }

    public String getimg(){
        return this._img;

    }

    public void setimgP (String imgP){
        this._imgP = imgP;
    }

    public String getimgP(){
        return this._imgP;
    }

    public void setsentvia(int sntvia){
        this._sntvia = sntvia;
    }

    public int getsentvia(){
        return this._sntvia;
    }

    public void setsentTime(String sentime ){
        this._snttime = sentime;
    }

    public String getsenttime(){
        return this._snttime;
    }

    public void settemp (String tmp ){
        this._template = tmp;
    }

    public String gettmp(){
        return this._template;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public sentdata(Parcel source){
        _id = source.readInt();
        _data = source.readString();
        _lat = source.readString();
        _long = source.readString();
        _img = source.readString();
        _imgP = source.readString();
        _sntvia = source.readInt();
        _snttime = source.readString();
        _template = source.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeInt(_id);     
        dest.writeString(_data);
        dest.writeString(_lat);
        dest.writeString(_long);
        dest.writeString(_img);
        dest.writeString(_imgP);
        dest.writeInt(_sntvia);
        dest.writeString(_snttime);
        dest.writeString(_template);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<sentdata> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<sentdata>() {

        @Override
        public sentdata createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new sentdata(source);
        }

        @Override
        public sentdata[] newArray(int size) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new sentdata[size];
        }   
    };
}
```

Please help me.. I don't really know what to do. I have other methods in mind but I don't want to let go of this simple method just because of the size of the data. There might be something else that I must do or don't know yet, Why it wont pass large size arraylist.

Comment: Instead of passing the data From One Activity to Another, You could save the data in some static field which can be accessible any where from the app.

Comment: what do you mean by static field?, Like a class or a database??

Comment: what is the size of sneardatalist ?

Comment: when the size hits 10 above.. it wont pass anything anymore.

Comment: would you please post your logcat ..

Comment: do you have the logcat. can you check if you are getting `!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!` there
or `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException`

Comment: Binder Transactions fail if the datasize exceeds 1MB. can you make sure if the ArrayList size is not more than 1MB

Comment: I have checked my logcat for errors but it does not display anything it just relaunches my **MainAcitivy** which is weird.

Comment: @pellucide thank you so much.. I did not know about that. I guess that is why.. it wont pass anything because my Array List contains many data and some of it even contains the base64 string format of  image. I'll conciser making my array list Global instead. thank you.

Comment: for such large data sizes Parcellable defeats the purpose(a fast communication channel). Please consider alternate methods.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with arraylist of parcelable objects set the parcelable objects to arraylist and pass that class object to the next activity through the bundle.